# Normal Counter vs Array Counter via function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Hello fellow good devs,

I am writing a node app and I encountered a counter problem, but this is probably a pure JS problem.

I wrote this test code (instead of my complicated problem) in order to present the issue more clearly.

```
 var func2 = function(i,counter,arrcounter)
{

  counter++;
  console.log('counter is ' + counter);

  arrcounter.push(i);

  console.log('arrcounter ' + arrcounter);


}



var looptest = function(){

var counter = 0;
var arrcounter = [];


for (var i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)


func2(i,counter,arrcounter);

}();
```

As you can see, I declared `var counter = 0` before the for loop, as well an array called `arrcounter`, and I passed it to `func2`, `func2` is being called at every iteration.

And I got this output:

```
counter is 1
arrcounter 0
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1,2
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1,2,3
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1,2,3,4
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1,2,3,4,5
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
counter is 1
arrcounter 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

As you can see above, the `arrcounter` was "incremented" corrected (not exactly the right term for array.push i know), yet the integer `counter` seems to being passed as 0 at every func2 call.

My question is, both the `counter` and `arrcounter` were declared before the `for loop`, 
why then the `arrcounter` "keeps track" correctly while the `counter` doesn't? And what's the right way to do for the `counter` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, primitive types are passed by value. In your case counter is also passed by value and changes made to it will not be reflected back. You push `i` in `arrCounter array` which is getting incemented that is why arrCounter array shows correct data. Your  `counter` variable is not a `global` variable and is passed by value to func2() , so changes made to it in `func2()` will not be reflected back, that is why it is always passed as 0 only.

If you will increment your counter variable and send its value to `Func2()`, it will start showing correct results, try the following:

```js
var func2 = function(i,counter,arrcounter)
{

 
  console.log('counter is ' + counter);

  arrcounter.push(i);

  console.log('arrcounter ' + arrcounter);


}



var looptest = function(){

var arrcounter = [];
var counter = 0;

for (var i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)


func2(i,counter++,arrcounter);

}();
```

Comment: but I tried to declare counter as global (above both looptest and func2, at the top of code) and still same effect.

Comment: @Sam that happens because you are re declaring a global variable inside your func2(), so it makes it local, and changes will not be reflected than. If you have made counter global than there is no need to pass it as  a parameter.

Comment: Hmm you are so right, when i removed it from the function's arguments, it incremented correctly.

Comment: global variables are bad idea and should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

```
 var func2 = function(i,counter,arrcounter)
{

  counter++;
  console.log('counter is ' + counter);

  arrcounter.push(i);

  console.log('arrcounter ' + arrcounter);


}
```

here counter parameter has been passed 0 at first. In javascript primitive type variables are passed by value , not by reference. Here variable counter is of type number and it's a primitive . So when it is passed to func2, a local variable counter will be created for func2. So, it will will increment the local counter parameter of func2 function, not the counter variable you have declared in looptest function

local counter parameter of func2 will be incremented to 1 but the variable counter you have declared in looptest function will remain unchanged.So, every time you wiil be feeding it with 0.

you can try the following :

```
var looptest = function(){

var counter = 0;
var arrcounter = [];


for (var i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{ 
   counter++;
   func2(i,counter,arrcounter);
}
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript variable point to objects. This is what assignments do — they point the lefthand to reference the righthand.

When you pass the variable `counter` into `func2` the argument points to object, in this case a number. When `func2` then reassigned the variable `counter` to a new object it takes the local `counter` variable and points it at a different number object. This has no effect on the variable `counter` in `looptest`. So every iteration of your for loop passes `0` to `func2`.

When you pass an array, it passes a reference to the array, so the array in `func2` is the same object as the array in `loopiest'. In 'func2' you don't reassign the variable`arr`, but rather alter the original object, so the changes are seen in the`looptest`. So you see the changes reflected in`looptest`

You can see this clearly in this example:

```js
function test(number, arr) {
    // reassign number 
    number = 10;
    // change arr
    arr.push(1)
    /* try reassigning arr instead for a comparison */
    // arr = [1] 
}

function start(){
    var number = 1
    var arr = []
    
    test(number, arr)
    
    // only arr has been changed
    console.log(number)
    console.log(arr)
}
start()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding of which parameters are passed by value and which by reference.

> *The paramters of a `function`...*
>
> **Primitives type** are passed **by value**.
>
> **Objects** (and Arrays) are passed **by reference**.

```js
var butImGlobal = 1;
var integerVar = 1;
var stringVar = 'change or not ?';
var array = [0,1];
var obj = {fruit: 'apple'};

function test(byvalInt, byvalTest, byrefArr, byrefObj){
 byvalInt = 99999;
 byvalTest = 'not change';
 byrefArr.push('I\'m new!');
 byrefObj.fruit = 'pineapple';
 butImGlobal = 'my value is changed, and I can change my type too!';
}


document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<b>BEFORE</b><br/>integerVar = ' + integerVar + '<br/>stringVar = ' + stringVar + '<br/>array = ' + array.join(', ') + '<br/>obj.fruit = ' + obj.fruit + '</br>butImGlobal = ' + butImGlobal;


test(integerVar, stringVar, array, obj);

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML +'<br/><br/><b>AFTER</b><br/>integerVar = ' + integerVar + '<br/>stringVar = ' + stringVar + '<br/>array = ' + array.join(', ') + '<br/>obj.fruit = ' + obj.fruit + '</br>butImGlobal = ' + butImGlobal;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```